# Accessing friend's friend's data using facebook api

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to access data from one friend's friend profile using facebook application?

Answer (score 1):

I think at the moment that is not possible, because the whole concept that an user has to grant your application before you can get his/her information, would fall apart.

Although, you could get a friend's friend, to see if they are related to each other.

[friends.areFriends](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.areFriends/)